# apache-spark - Unparseable number Issue while writing data to parquet file from Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I created a dataframe in Spark and loaded the data in the dataframe from AWS S3. When I'm writing the data to parquet from dataframe, it throws a following error:

> Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number:
>   "$250.00-$254.99"     at
>   java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:385)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$$anonfun$castTo$2.apply$mcF$sp(CSVInferSchema.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$$anonfun$castTo$2.apply(CSVInferSchema.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$$anonfun$castTo$2.apply(CSVInferSchema.scala:261)

I do have a column in my dataset which has the value "$250.00-$254.99" and this column is defined as StringType in my dataframe.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: can you share the code so that error can be replicated ?

Comment: I have the same issue,